# Al modificar o actualizar un post no devuelve un objeto HTTPResponse

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Iniciandome en Django me encontre con un problema que no puedo solucionar.

La aplicación es un blog. del tutorial de DjangoGirl.

Se agradece al inestimable ayuda.

Cuando quiero agregar un post desde un formulario o quiero actualizar un post me tira el siquiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en urls.py el codigo es el siguiente:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.post_list),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.post_detail, name= 'post_detail'),
    url(r'^post/new/$', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
    url(r'^post/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/edit/$', views.post_edit, name= 'post_edit')
]
```

y en views.py el codigo es el siguiente:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_list(request):
    posts =  Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post':post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = PostForm(request.GET)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = PostForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

def post_edit(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "GET":
        form = PostForm(request.GET,instance=post)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            form = PostForm(instance=post)
        return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: El error te dice `REQUEST METHOD = POST`, pero ¿Qué retorna `post_new` en este caso? Efecticamente `None`. Ten en cuanta que el condicional que tienes es `if request.method == "GET"` por lo que para `POST` la función tiene el retorno por defecto de toda función/método Python, `None`...

Answer (score 0):

Usa GET en lugar de POST... no se si estas haciendo el front con templates o usas postman para probar.. si usas html seria algo asi como
 `<form method="GET"> tus inputs </form>`... o en su defecto pon el if como:
`if request.method == "GET" or request.method == "POST":`

Answer (score 0):

El primer problema está con la tabulación ya que seguro copiastes el código y lo pegastes pero no te distes cuenta de que ese `else` no pertenece a ese `if`, debería ser de esta forma:

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

de la forma en que lo tenias declarado el `else` pertenecía a la condición `if form.is_valid():` cuando deberia perteneces a: `if request.method == "POST":` por eso no retornaba nada.

Answer (score 0):

solucione el problema agregandole un else a if form.is_valid()

```
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
        else:
            return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})
```